# How do I make my mineflayer sprint while he following me?

Tags: javascript, mineflayer

I'm making mineflayer bot he follow me and try to kill me so when I go far from him he stop from
following me, And he has other problems like while he bridge he fall as stupid so how I can make him sprint while he follow me
My **code** :

```
const { versions } = require('minecraft-data')
const MinecraftData = require('minecraft-data')
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
const { pathfinder, Movements, goals } = require('mineflayer-pathfinder')
const GoalFollow = goals.GoalFollow
const pvp = require('mineflayer-pvp').plugin
const armorM = require('mineflayer-armor-manager')

const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    host: 'EventWG.aternos.me',
    username: 'bot'
})

//Follow the player
function followPlayer() {
    
    bot.on('chat', (namee, msgg)=>{
        const player = bot.players[namee]
        if (msgg == "attack") {
            bot.chat("ok " + namee)
            bot.chat("/effect give @p minecraft:resistance 111111 255")
            if (!player || !player.entity){
                bot.chat("I can't see you " + namee) 
                return
            }
        
            const data = require('minecraft-data')(bot.version)
            const movements = new Movements(bot, data)
            bot.pathfinder.setMovements(movements)
        
            const goal = new GoalFollow(player.entity, 2)
            bot.pathfinder.setGoal(goal, true)
        
            setInterval(() => {
                const playerFilter = p => p.type === "player"
                const playerr = bot.nearestEntity(playerFilter)
                bot.pvp.attack(player.entity)
                const sword = bot.inventory.items().find(item => item.name.includes('sword'))
                if(sword) bot.equip(sword, "hand")
            }, 2000);
        
        }
    })


}

bot.on('spawn', lookAtPlayer)
bot.on('spawn', followPlayer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple just use bot.setControlState just like

```
bot.setControlState('sprint', true);
```